# How to run multiple test cases under one script while sharing different setup and teardown methods?

Tags: android, python, appium

I'm currently trying to do automate mobile testing and am wondering if there is any way that I can define different setup() methods (for example having different appPackage, appActivity) and run the test cases in the same script.

For example, I have written the below code that it will automate sending a message (appPackage is com.android.mms and appActivity is com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList). But after selecting the option to add an attachment I need to add a picture which will then be using the appPackage is com.android.documentsui and appActivity is com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity), which is the action defined under case3 on my code.

How can I handle this in the same script? Thanks in advance.

```
import os, sys
import glob
import unittest
from appium import webdriver
from time import sleep

PLATFORM_VERSION = '5.1.1'


class EntranceTests(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    print 'commandline args',sys.argv[1]
    desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
    desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '5.1.1'
    desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'android'    
    desired_caps['udid'] = sys.argv[1] 
    desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.android.mms'
    desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList'
    url = "http://localhost:{}/wd/hub".format(sys.argv[2])
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote(url, desired_caps)



def case2(self):
    addmsg = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.ImageButton[contains(@index, "0")]')
    addmsg.click()

    editreceiver = self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.android.mms:id/recipients_editor')
    editreceiver.send_keys("0713414713")

    message = self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.android.mms:id/embedded_text_editor_btnstyle')
    message.send_keys("Test Message")

    attachment = self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.android.mms:id/add_attachment_second')
    attachment.click()

    addpic = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, "Pictures")]')
    addpic.click()

    sendmsg = self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.android.mms:id/first_send_button_sms_view')
    sendmsg.click()



def case3(self):
    pic = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.ImageView[contains(@index, "0")]')
    pic.click()



def testcase2(self):
    self.case2()
    self.case3()


def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(EntranceTests)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Comment: Any reason to write case 3 ? you could have continued with case 2 in sequential manner..

Comment: @pankajmishra - Even if I have continued with case 2 in sequential manner, still the problem arise.  The script only runs til the end of case 2, which means I cannot get the click event for pic.

Answer (score 0):

To switch between apps, you use `start_activity()`. For your case, it will be -

```
def case3(self):
    pic = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.ImageView[contains(@index, "0")]')
    pic.click()
    self.driver.start_activity("com.android.documentsui", "com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity")
    #do soemthing in the new app
```